# Question about terminology, and reference request related to the braid operad

Tags: operads, braid-groups, braided-tensor-categories

Let $\Delta_n$ stand for the Garside element of the braid group $B_n$.  It turns out that the family of all Garside elements have the following ``operadic'' property:
$$
\Delta_n\left[ \Delta_{k_1},\ldots, \Delta_{k_n} \right] = \Delta_{k_1 + \ldots + k_n}
$$
where for braids $\beta, \beta_1,\ldots,\beta_n$, the symbol $\beta \left[ \beta_1,\ldots, \beta_n \right]$ stands for cabling: replace the $i$ strand of $\beta$ with $\beta_i$.

I need this property for a paper and I have a straightforward (and a bit tedious) proof of this, but I would prefer to not have to write it.  So my first question is:

1. Has anybody else come across this? Is this written somewhere?  If so a reference would be greatly appreciated.
2. And my second question: I call this property ``operadic'' because braids form an operad under cabling, but I'm not using operads really in my work.  Is there an other more suitable name for this concept, a family of operations in an operad that is closed under compositions?

**Update and answer after five years**.  I ended up writing up a rather tedious inductive proof but my gut feeling about it was right: there is the following easy proof: Clearly any such cabling is positive, non-repeating, and induces the flip permutation, properties also enjoyed by the Garside element.  Since the map from positive non-repeating braids to the symmetric group is a bijection if follows that any such cabling is indeed equal to the Garside element.

Comment: For (2), you can speak of a suboperad, I suppose.

Comment: Thanks that make sense.  It's rather cacophonous though.

Comment: I have no clue about Q1, but for Q2: the relation you have written not only means that the collection $\Delta_\bullet = \{ \Delta_n\}_{n \ge 0}$ is a (non-symmetric) suboperad of the braid operad, it also means that it is isomorphic to the  associative operad. $\Delta_1$ is the identity, $\Delta_2$ is the product, and $\Delta_n$ is obtained as $\Delta_2[\Delta_2[\dots[\Delta_2[\Delta_1,\Delta_1], \dots, \Delta_1]]$ (I hope it's clear, the same way that $a_1\dots a_n = (\dots((a_1 a_2)a_3) \dots a_n)$ in a monoid). I really wouldn't this give the name just "operadic"...

Comment: @Najib Idrissi  That's cool, thank you.  This is definitely more interesting than just "closed under compositions".

Comment: I used Najib's remark at the paper, and acknowledged this comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1804.01214